# Connecting Java to a Database?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have connected Java to MySQL DB with the following code and it is working, Can anyone explain me what each line does?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.1/test","USERNAME","SATHE");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
```

Answer (score 2):

First line loads the database driver by loading the driver class, because, I guess, the DriverManager looks for loaded classes that are jdbc drivers.

Second establishes connection to the database with given path, username and password. It returns you a connection object that allows you to manipulate the session, prepare statements etc.

Third creates a statement. `Statement` object is used for executing queries.

Comment: +1 Note that ".newInstance()" is not necessary. Just just need to load the class to register it with the `DriverManager`, not create an instance of it.

Comment: As a side note, DriverManager does not discover classes, it is told about them, as Shengyuan mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

```
// loads the vendor specific jdbc library - there are many to choose from
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

// this is what tells the library to connect, using the vendor specific pattern
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.1/test","USERNAME","SATHE");

// this prepares the statement from the connection.
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note in 1.6 there is no need for driver registration line:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

As the [`DriverManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) will discover the Driver automatically assuming the jar is on the class-path.

Comment: pretty sure that is not true.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you read the javadoc for DriverManager and then go and have a look in the jar for a recent jdbc driver, say like mysql's you will find the required /META-INF/services file

Comment: i stand corrected.  I didn't realize jdbc 4.0 added support for the service providers mechanism.  your last statement is slightly misleading: the jar in question must include the appropriate services file.  And, pulling up the mysql jar on my system indicates that it does _not_ include this file.

Comment: assuming you are not connecting to multiple databases and the wrong one is found ;-)

Comment: @vickirk if multiple Drivers regsister for the same jdbc url i.e. two attempt to handle jdbc:mysql then you are in a world of pain what ever you do with DriverManager.

Answer (score 0):

When `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is loaded in JVM by `Class.forName()`, some methods such as  `DriverManager.registerDriver()` will be invoked by `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. That is, mysql registers itself in DriverManager. So `DriverManager.getConnection()` could work.

You could read java source `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to discover it.